# escapeshellarg() has been disabled - cronjob - Magento 2

Tags: magento-2.1, cron, crontab

I get this error after installing Magento 2 and enabling the cronjob.
The error appears in the email/logfile of the following cronjob:

**/usr/local/bin/php -f /home/craftweb/domains/craftseurope.eu/public_html/bin/magento cron:run**

*[Exception]
  Warning: escapeshellarg() has been disabled for security reasons in /home/craftweb/domains/craftseurope.eu/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Shell/CommandRenderer.php on line 19

cron:run [--group="..."] [--bootstrap="..."]*

Can I deny this one or is there a fix? I don't know if it now works correctly.
Maybe someone can give me those insights.

Answer (score 0):

Make your own escapeshellarg:

At the end of `CommandRenderer.php` file add a function:

```
public function my_escapeshellarg($input)
{
    $input = str_replace('\'','\\\'', $input);
    return '\''.$input.'\'';
}
```

and substitute the line above with

```
$arguments = array_map('my_escapeshellarg', $arguments);
```

Or more your store to another host different than mine